# How can I use a variable inside the function with the map command that is defined outside the function in python?

Tags: python, function, variables, global-variables

```
new_pattern = ''
def create_pattern(letter):
    new_pattern += f'{letter}|{letter.upper()}'
    print(new_pattern)


list(map(create_pattern, pattern))
```

I want to use new pattern in create_pattern function but it shows an UnboundLocalError
and this error cannot be fixed by using global

Answer (score 1):

You need the `global` keyword:

```
new_pattern = ''
def create_pattern(letter):
    global new_pattern
    new_pattern += f'{letter}|{letter.upper()}'
    print(new_pattern)


list(map(create_pattern, pattern))
```

Answer (score -1):

If the intent is to build up a value for `new_pattern` using an initial pattern and a list of letters, use `functools.reduce` instead of `map`.

```
from functools import reduce

pattern = 'aeiou'
new_pattern = reduce(lambda p, l: p + f'{l}{l.upper()}', pattern, '')

assert new_pattern == 'aAeEiIoOuU'
```